# In constructing matrices to model physical phenomena, are real matrices superior to complex matrices, in terms of computational cost?

Tags: numerical-analysis, matrix

Just studying some toy examples of $2\times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ matrices, complex number multiplication already gets a bit messy.

From a numerical analysis point of view, if one were to try and build very large matrices to model physical behavior, is it much more desirable to build *real* matrices over complex matrices, in terms of computational cost?

What other advantages are there regarding real vs. complex matrices?

Comment: A very similar question : http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/power-of-complex-valued-neural-network

Answer (score 9):

The question is ill-posed -- you don't say what you mean by "desirable" or "superior". If a phenomenon I try to model involves only real numbers, then clearly using real matrices is the better way. On the other hand, if I try to model something in the Fourier domain, then complex numbers appear and I would try to use a matrix with complex elements, rather than split the whole thing into two matrices. Finally, if I tried to write the fastest code for matrix-matrix multiplication, I may actually try to store the real and imaginary parts separately.

So it always comes down to what exactly you're trying to do -- there is no answer so general that it is always true.